# Get list of all includes for project compiled with GNU autotools

Tags: c, header-files, configure, autotools

For a C project managed and successfully compiled using GNU autotools, eg. emacs, is there a simple way to get a list of all the included headers that *were* required to compile the project (the site-specific include paths that were found by the `configure` script during compilation)?

My current approach has just been to

1. run `cpp -C ...`
2. look at the error for a missing header
3. manually add the path to the required header to my command
4. repeat until there are no more errors.

Obviously, this is a pain.  I would think a project compiled using `configure` would have this information somewhere.  Does it?

Comment: `gcc -MM myfile.c`

Comment: @wildplasser that doesn't take into account any configuration does it?  It seems `pkg-config --cflags-only-I` would work, but I have to look into how to create the config file I think

Comment: also, it doesn't account for includes to any non-standard locations that would be found with `configure`, eg. `pkg-config --cflags-only-I cairo`

Comment: Umm... Try to `make` and install headers until it works? Usually the project lists its dependencies.

Comment: I assume that this is an XY problem, and you're trying to find all the include files needed to compile a project (e.g. emacs) without looking at the dependency list?

Comment: I have no problem compiling these projects as they are managed with autotools.  You're probably familiar with autotools - but it will find and configure paths specific to the site.  I need the site-specific paths (my specific use-case right now is for macroexpansion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For a C project managed and compiled using GNU autotools, eg. emacs,
>   is there a simple way to get a list of all the included headers that
>   *were* required to compile the project?

If by "were required" you mean that you want to make the determination after the project is successfully built, then yes.  Unless suppressed, Automake-based makefiles have rules for generating include-dependency lists, which they use on subsequent builds to recognize the need to rebuild unchanged sources on account of changes to dependencies.  You can find these files in the `.deps` subdirectory.

For what it's worth, when compiling with `gcc`, the `gcc -MM` command is used for the purpose.

Comment: thanks, yes that was what I meant, and this is what I was looking for.  However, this doesn't help much since the .d files only have local dependencies.  So, I still need to add all system include paths manually (that aren't in the standard directories)

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, `gcc -MM` ignores headers found in system header directories.  This is what distinguishes it from `gcc -M`, which lists all includes.  I suppose you could modify the makefile after generating it to replace the former with the latter.

Comment: right, I understand that.  The generated makefiles do already have all the system paths, though, in variables like `DBUS_CFLAGS` that are determined by `configure`.  There just doesn't seem to be a standard way, no target, to list them.  I thought there would be, eg. to generate a `pkg-config` file -- the `pkg-config` man page even says the file would probably be generated by `configure`, but doesn't expand on that

Comment: I believe the autoconf macro is `AC_CHECK_MODULES` or `PKG_CHECK_MODULES` that create these standard `*_CFLAGS` variables

Comment: last note, `gcc -M` isn't sufficient since it doesn't find non-standard locations (as `configure` would using `pkg-config`), so any system includes it returned would already be found by default anyway

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, `gcc -M` finds the actual resolution of each `#include` directive processed, subject to the compile flags in effect.  As used in an Automake-based build script, this is done in conjunction with regular compilation, not separately, so what ends up getting written to `.deps` reflects what is actually used, whether in standard directories or not.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, a build system that wants to create a `pkg-config` file might indeed choose to do so via its `configure` script, but that's a general sentiment, not an allusion to any special capability of Autoconf.  It simply happens to be that to do its job, `configure` has to be written with knowledge of what dependencies need to be accounted for, and it has -- or reasonably can be assigned -- responsibility for locating them.  That makes it well suited for emitting `pkg-config` data.

Comment: yea, I see what you mean -- rebuild the depends entirely using -M.  I don't know why I interpreted that as running outside the makefile.  It might work, but wouldn't simplify things, and would make the depends brittle themselves

Comment: ok, it still seems like it could be a standard target though.  Configure would know the dependencies the user specified and could output the proper cflags accordingly

Comment: I guess I'll just accept this isn't directly supported by autotools and write my own script. Thanks!